# How do I replace OpenJDK 6 with OpenJDK 7 on Debian?

Tags: debian, openjdk

I have just installed the `openjdk-7-jdk` and `openjdk-7-jre` packages on my Debian box that already had OpenJDK 6 installed on it. However, when I look at my Java version, I see that it shows OpenJDK 6:

```
bui@debian:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (6b24-1.11.3-2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
bui@debian:~$
```

I did a bit of searching but found no answer on how to "replace" the old version with the new one (I did find a [solution for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64329/how-to-replace-openjdk-6-with-openjdk-7) but the command used there isn't available for me).

Could anyone tell me how I should proceed?

Comment: What command is unavailable? `update-java-alternatives`? If yes, why?

Comment: It doesn't exist for me.

Comment: On my Debian Squeeze box, it is provided by `java-common` package. Check if it is listed in “Installed Files” for `java-common`, and if it is present in `/usr/sbin/`. I just checked, on my box it is only available under `root` for some reason — maybe the situation is the same for you?

Comment: Now I get this when setting the alternative: `update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so for mozilla-javaplugin.so not registered, not setting.`

Answer (score 1):

The java version still shows OpenJDK 6 and not OpenJDK 7 because the defaultJDK is still pointing to OpenJDK 6. To solve this, we need to change the default JDK. The command below will help.

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```